# pl/sql java source class errorjavax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet

Tags: java, oracle, xslt, plsql

I'm transforming xml with xslt and java extension inside oracle database

When I pars the xml with xsl I'm getting the error:

```
errorjavax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:858)
```

I have tested without extending the xslt and it works ok.
Also I have tested the transformation in an other environement and it works ok.

The java version is 1.6.0_43.

The xslt is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/XsltTransformer"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="APSDocument">
    <atag  value='{java:GetDateTimeNow()}' ></atag>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML:

> ```
> <APSDocument Tag="APP002">
>   <Section Tag="APPLICATION_FINISHED">
>     <SectionBody>
>       <Field Tag="APP_FINISHED">1</Field>
>     </SectionBody>
>   </Section>
> </APSDocument>
> ```

The the java class:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "XsltTransformer" AS
    import java.io.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.xml.parsers.*;
    import javax.xml.transform.*;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.w3c.dom.*;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException; 
    import java.sql.*;

    public class XsltTransformer
    {
        public static String TransformToSvTLV(String xmlDoc, String xsltDoc) throws Exception

        {

          try

          {
            XsltTransformer xsltTransformer = new XsltTransformer();
            Document svmlDoc = xsltTransformer.TransformToSvML(xmlDoc, xsltDoc);
            return xsltTransformer.TransformSvMLToStTlv(svmlDoc);

          } catch (Exception e)
          {

              StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
              PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
              e.printStackTrace(pw);
              return sw.toString();
          }
        }

        private Document TransformToSvML(String xmlDoc, String xsltDoc) throws Exception
        {

           TransformerFactory tFactory=TransformerFactory.newInstance();
           Source xslSourceDoc=new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltDoc)); 
           Source xmlSourceDoc=new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlDoc));
           StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

           Transformer trasform=tFactory.newTransformer(xslSourceDoc);
           trasform.transform(xmlSourceDoc, new StreamResult(writer));

           //System.out.println(writer.toString());


           DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
           Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(writer.toString())));
           doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

           return doc;
        }

        public static String GetDateTimeNow()
        {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
            return simpleDateFormat.format((new Date())).replace('/', '.');
        }

        private String TransformXmlNodeToSvTlv(Node svmlNode, String endChar)throws Exception
        {
           return "do nothing";
        }

}
```

Calling the TransformToSvTLV method:

```
 FUNCTION EtlTransformToSvXML(xmlDoc LONG,xsltDoc LONG) RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME
 'XsltTransformer.TransformToSvTLV(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 return java.lang.String';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the **TransformSvMLToStTlv** method in the code?

Comment: @nawazlj I have edited the post with the calling of TransformToSvTLV  method.

Comment: A remark, hh is for 12 hour display, HH for 24 hour (as you are not using AM/PM).

Comment: As I understand [this doc (section 'Java format namespace')](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html), the java call from xslt must be prefixed with the class name, ie. `<atag  value='{java:XsltTransformer.GetDateTimeNow()}' ></atag>`.

Comment: Not exatly, this is a static method, and the prefix refers specifically to the class: xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/XsltTransformer",

Also i have tried calling directly via class path, but still doesn;t work.

Comment: It seems you forgot to provide an instance of an XML document on which the transformation is to be applied. Please, do.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev i have added the xml,. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Most probable problem in this case is the program is not able to read the xslt file.
Possible soluion I would suggest is to use

```
new StreamSource(new File("path/to/your/xslt"))
```

Comment: Not exactly,  the xslt is passed as string not as path reference:                 Source xslSourceDoc=new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsltDoc));

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with oracle or xalan but I seen issues similar to this in other other environment. With this in mind and consider the question has been active for some time, I'm going out on a limb here to make a suggestion rather then provide an possible answer.

Often xsl compiler failures are due to a problem with namespaces or permissions (especially in regards to being hosted within databases).  My layman understanding is that the xslt processor will attempt to create an instance of the extension class during compilation of the xslt. If this is correct, then having the correct namespace and permissions will be significant.

The only example I've seen using xslt function extensions in oracle uses a namespace-uri as follows:  "http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/classname"  where *classname* is **fully qualified** (i.e. *module.class*).  Of course, your URI root may differ but I'd certain be considering this as a possible cause for the error.

Comment: Not exatly, this is a static method, and the prefix refers specifically to the class: xmlns:java="xml.apache.org/xalan/java/XsltTransformer";, Also i have tried calling directly via class path, but still doesn;t work.